# How can I make a ball oscillate after being attracted to a certain point?

Tags: mass, computational-physics, spring, simulations

I have a ball that needs to oscillate around a certain point (mass spring), I've posted 2 more post that really helped me out figuring how to do that (unfortunately there were closed, I'll try do a better one now).
the formula was

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& A e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \phi) + x_{eq} \\
y(t) &=& B e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \psi) + y_{eq} \\
\end{eqnarray}

where $A$ and $B$ are the amplitude, $\gamma$ is the friction, $x_{eq}$ and $y_{eq}$ are the equilibrium, $\omega$ is the frequency, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are set (for the moment) to zero and $t$ is time.

Now I have few problems with this formula:

let's say I have an origin $x_0$ and $x_0$, $A$ and $B$ is the distance between $x_0$ and $x_{eq}$ and $y_0$ and $y_{eq}$. so when I click on the point on my screen (the equilibrium) the point directly starts there. The desired behaviour would be that my ball starts from $x_0$ and $y_0$ get attracted to the touched point ($x_{eq}$ and $y_{eq}$) with a certain attraction factor (velocity I guess) and only when the ball reaches the equilibrium it's starts oscillating because of the force of attraction. One more thing is that when I stop pressing my mouse to the given equilibrium the ball keeps moving in the desired direction meaning there is no mass spring at all (it releases the spring), only a direction and an attraction and speed factor.

I'm not a physicist neither a mathematician, simple explanation and formula (without derivative if possible) are greatly appreciated. please tell me if I'm unclear I'll try improve my post as much as possible.

Comment: Have you tried plotting $x(t)$?

Comment: withe the words "so when I click on the point on my screen" you seem to have a computerprogramm for your moving ball? So how does your program decide where the starting point is? It should be at x=Acos(-\phi)+xeq. So without your programm I can say nothing, the formula is ok if \phi =0  the ball should start at the extreme position.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the purpose of visualization, I think you can think of your ball as rolling on a horizontal table with the spring attached to the equilibrium point (and the axis of rotation of the ball).  Given an initial velocity the ball would tend to move in an ellipse (with the shape determined by A and B).  The spring supplies the centripetal acceleration. Then the x and y components of motion are oscillations and are out of phase (by about 90 degrees), and the ellipse is shrinking due to friction. Given the x and y components of position as a function of time, you can find the components of velocity and acceleration.    It is not likely that a spring would supply the required centripetal acceleration.

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay. Should I change my formula? Did you had a chance downloading the app I've put in my first post. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I assumed you were looking for a 2D motion described by the given formulas.  If you need formulas to match a given motion, you need to be more clear in your description of the motion.

Comment: I've added description to my post, but basically the formula looks good but I'm not sure if it's sufficient for my whole motion.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We discussed some of this in your closed post...

To oscillate near $(2,3)$ do $2+x(t)$ for the $x$ co-ordinate and $3+y(t)$ for the $y$ co-ordinate (where $x(t)$ etc.. are without the $x_{eq}$..).

You might need to reduce the A and B if necessary for a smaller oscillation.

If you want it to travel from $(x_0,y_0)$ first, you'll have start with what you have already and then change the formula to the above when the ball gets close enough to the equilibrium position.

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay $x_{eq}$ and $y_{eq}$ is supposed to be 2, 3. I'm not sure to understand, sorry. My main concern (and that's something I didn't wrote in the post) is that velocity of ball is related to it's oscillation, I don't know how to relate both of them in a formula. for example if I click on the point without holding the mouse pressed the ball continue moving in the direction without stopping to the equelibrium. Did you had a chance downloading the app I've put in my first post. Many thanks.

Comment: @JSmith, this will have to be be the last comment, the $\omega$ changes the speed and reduce A and B to keep it near the equilibrium position.  If you want it to travel there, have A, B larger until it's near, then swap to a smaller A and B, all the best with it